# ServiceStack SOAP Error serialization

Tags: c#, iis, soap, servicestack

In a ServiceStack project I've added api key authorization as follows

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    var apiKey = req.Headers["X-ApiKey"];
    if (apiKey == null || !ApiKeyValidation.VerifyKey(apiKey))
    {
        throw HttpError.Unauthorized("Unknown ApiKey");
    }
});
```

When accessing the service via REST I get a response as I expect:

```
{
    "ResponseStatus": {
        "ErrorCode": "Unknown ApiKey",
        "Message": "Unknown ApiKey"
    }
}
```

When accessing the SOAP 1.2 endpoint, I get an HTML response from the IIS server with an error message and stacktrace. This seems to happen for other (Input string was not in a correct format) errors as well.

```
Unknown ApiKey

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpError: Unknown ApiKey
```

My DTO's are written as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class UserDetails : IReturn<UserDetailsResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class UserDetailsResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public Account User { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I've set the DebugMode = false in the configuration. Am I missing some configuration option?

Comment: Are you sure your client is sending the X-ApiKey header?

Comment: I'm sure I'm **not** sending the header, and that is the problem. I want a properly serialized ResponseStatus telling me what the problem is like what happens with the REST service. The way it returns now I get a big error at the client side seeing as the HTML response is not in a SOAP format.

Comment: Completely misread your question there. Sorry about that @Taesti

Comment: @Taesti Were you able to find a solution for this? I'm running into the same kind of problems as well