# Servicestack SOAP - Invalid credentials returning html in response

Tags: c#, soap, servicestack

In my service, I have a custom auth provider that throws a HttpError if the credentials are invalid like so:

```
throw HttpError.Unauthorized("Invalid Username or Password");
```

When I access this service via REST and purposely enter invalid credentials, I get the expected response:

```
{
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "Unauthorized",
    "Message": "Invalid UserName or Password",
  }
}
```

However, doing the same thing via a SOAP client, I get a Html response from the IIS server:

[image]

This causes my SOAP client to break as it can't deserialize the response. This can also occur if incorrect data values are included in the request e.g. setting a string value on an integer parameter. The response is fine if an exception occurs in one of my services where I am handling the request (i.e. HttpError.NotFound thrown). I know a similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824944/servicestack-soap-error-serialization) but it hasn't been updated since 2013. Is there a way to configure the response or override it?

**Edit 1**

I've updated my web.config to look like so (in system.webServer, I had to use "modules" instead of "httpModules".):

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="FormsAuthenticationDisposition" type="ServiceStack.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule, ServiceStack" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="FormsAuthenticationDisposition" type="ServiceStack.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule, ServiceStack" />
    </modules>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

and my AppHost has the following:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig
{
    HandlerFactoryPath = "/api"
});

SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule.PathToSupress = Config.HandlerFactoryPath;
```

However I'm still getting the same error as before. I'm wondering if this is due to me passing in credentials as a header with every request rather than specifically authenticating first? It's worth pointing out that this same error occurs when e.g. a string is set on an integer parameter.

**Edit 2**

This solution does in fact work. I was defining the incorrect HandlerFactoryPath:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig
{
    HandlerFactoryPath = "api"
});
```

Comment: One suggestion (based on the way we implemented a service call) is: Construct the "exact" response you want to send, for eg
`return new HttpResponseMessage() 
 {
        Content = new StringContent(result),
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
};
`
In this way you can full control over output.

Comment: @Subbu This problem can also occur if incorrect data values are included in the request e.g. setting a string value on an integer parameter. In this situation I cannot control the response that servicestack generates. I've edited my question to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Yellow Screen Of Death is the result of ASP.NET Hijacking the Error Response of Unauthorized Error Responses. You can [prevent ASP.NET from hijacking the Error Response](http://docs.servicestack.net/form-hijacking-prevention) with the `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule`.

First you need to register the HTTP Module in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="FormsAuthenticationDisposition" type="ServiceStack.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule, ServiceStack" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>

<!-- Required for IIS 7.0 (and above?) -->
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="FormsAuthenticationDisposition" type="ServiceStack.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule, ServiceStack" />
    </httpModules>
</system.webServer>
```

next, configure the module with where your API lives - defaults to /api, so in your AppHost Configure:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new HostConfig {
        HandlerFactoryPath = "api",
    });

    //this is the configuration for Hijacking prevention
    SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule.PathToSupress = Config.HandlerFactoryPath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this out but no difference for me. I'm wondering if this is because I'm trying to pre-authenticate as part of each request? I'll edit my question above.

Comment: @Dan_Dan_Man ServiceStack Auth is completely decoupled from ASP.NET Auth so ASP.NET doesn't "know" you're trying to Authenticate other than returning a 401 Unauthorised which it's pre programmed to hijack, can you change HandlerFactoryPath to just "api" to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Ah that did it thank you! Now correctly seeing a 401 response when entering incorrect credentials. I'll accept your answer but I'm wondering if you know how to handle situations where a user may for example, enter a string into an integer parameter? I get back a html response in that situation as well.

Comment: @Dan_Dan_Man ServiceStack should only return HTML pages for clients that accept text/html e.g when sent from browsers, if the Response is an ASP.NET HTML page then that's being handled by ASP.NET again which it can do when sending illegal XSS characters